# How to reload a controller when pressing back (angular js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I hav a controller responsible for navigation, it checks the cookie and if the user is logged in shows and hides navigation menu.

nav.js - controller

```
'use strict';

//app global variable
//this is the controller that handles post requests
//declare services as dependecies $http, $location, custom service apiServiceWeb
app.controller('navigationController', function($scope, $route, $rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies, setCredentials) {
    //get what is in the cookie
    var cookieValue = setCredentials.getCookie('globals');

    if (cookieValue == '[object Object]') {
        //redirect to home
        $location.path("/");
        //remove cookie
        //setCredentials.removeCookie('globals');
    }

    //hide menu in certain paths 
    if ($location.path() == '/' || $location.path() == 'signup' || cookieValue == '[object Object]') {
        //hide menu
        $scope.isConnected = true;
    } else {
        $rootScope.$watch('globals', function() {
            //if a currentUser does NOT exist, the hide menu.
            console.log('changed');
            // console.log($rootScope.globals);

            if (cookieValue = null) {
                $scope.isConnected = true;
            } else {
                //show menu, user is logged in
                $scope.isConnected = false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

However the problem is, if the user clicks back and they end up in the login page. The nav.js controller does not reload, meaning the menu that shows when the user is logged in, shows on the login page.

So far I have detected when the user clicks back, like this:

app.js

```
/* global app:true */
/* exported app */
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name WebAppApp
 * @description
 * # WebAppApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
var app = angular
    .module('WebAppApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
    ])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
        //  controllerAs: 'login'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        resolve: {
            "checkLoggedIn": function($location, $cookies, $rootScope) {
                if (!$cookies.get('globals')) {
                    $location.path('/');
                }
            }
        },
    //controllerAs: 'home'
    })
    .when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
        controller: 'signupCtrl',
        //controllerAs: 'home'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

//when app runs call this function.
app.run(function($rootScope, $route, $location){
    //Bind the `$locationChangeSuccess` event on the rootScope, so that we dont need to 
    //bind in induvidual controllers.

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
        $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
    });        

    $rootScope.$watch(function () {return $location.path()}, function (newLocation, oldLocation) {
        if($rootScope.actualLocation === newLocation) {
            alert('Why did you use history back?');
            alert($rootScope.actualLocation);
            if($rootScope.actualLocation=='/'){
              //clear cookie
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I basically would like to reload the nav.js controller once I detect the user is back to the login page or other pages where the nav bar should not appear.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks